# Copy S3 objects with "subdirectories" using s3Client.copyObject method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3

I have an S3-Bucket with two files:

```
s3://bucketA/objectA/objectB/fileA
s3://bucketA/objectA/objectB/fileB
```

I want to use the `s3Client` in java to create a copy of `objectA` known as `objectC` using the `copyObject` method of `s3Client`.

```
s3://bucketA/objectA/ ---Copy-To---> s3://bucketA/objectC/
```

The problem is the contents of `objectA` are not being copied into `objectC`. Object C does not contain object B and fileA and fileB. How can I copy the contents of the object as well?

Here is my code: (I am using kotlin)

```kotlin
s3client.copyObject(CopyObjectRequest("bucketA", "objectA","bucketA", "objectC"))
```

I checked in the S3 console and this works (it creates a folder called objectC, but I'm unable to get the contents of objectA into object C.)

Comment: How are you creating your s3Client?

Comment: using AmazonS3ClientBuilder()

Comment: Can you add the full code and what you are doing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that using the SDK you're not making a `recursive copy` of the objects.

So the **easiest solution** is to use the AWS CLI

```
aws s3 cp s3://source-awsexamplebucket s3://source-awsexamplebucket --recursive --storage-class STANDARD
```

Note that you've to take into consideration the size of the objects, the amount, etc. If its something too big a batch mechanism could be made to help your system cope with load. You can read it further [on the AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-transfer-between-buckets/).

Now, and assuming you need to be doing that programmatically. The algorithm has 2 parts listing + copying. Something along those lines will work.

```
ListObjectsV2Result result = s3.listObjectsV2(from_bucket);
List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = result.getObjectSummaries();

for (S3ObjectSummary os : objects) {
    s3.copyObject(from_bucket, os.getKey(), to_bucket, os.getKey());
}

// exception handling and error handling ommited for brevity
```

Comment: Hey Ricardo, couldn't add full code as it was proprietary code, but I got it resolved now thanks!

Comment: Of course that's what matters I hope that I'd help!